# PLPGSQL array assignment not working, "array subscript in assignment must not be null"

Tags: arrays, loops, types, for-loop, plpgsql

When assigning mobilenumbers to a varchar[] in a loop through results it gives me the following error:

"array subscript in assignment must not be null"

Also, i think the query that joins member uuids, and group member uuids, into one, grouped on the user_id, i think it can be done better, or maybe this is even why it is going wrong in the first place!

Any help is very appreciated..

Thank you very much!

```
CREATE  OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_membermessage(in_company_uuid uuid, in_user_uuid uuid, in_destinationmemberuuids uuid[], in_destinationgroupuuids uuid[], in_title character varying, in_messagecontents character varying, in_timedelta interval, in_messagecosts numeric, OUT out_status integer, OUT out_status_description character varying, OUT out_value VARCHAR[], OUT out_trigger uuid[]) RETURNS record
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $$

DECLARE
    temp_count INTEGER;
    temp_costs NUMERIC;
    temp_balance NUMERIC;
    temp_campaign_uuid UUID;
    temp_record RECORD;
    temp_mobilenumbers VARCHAR[];
    temp_destination_uuids UUID[];
    temp_iterator INTEGER;
BEGIN

 out_status := NULL;
 out_status_description := NULL;
 out_value := NULL;
 out_trigger := NULL;



    SELECT INTO temp_count COUNT(*) FROM costs WHERE costtype = 'MEMBERMESSAGE' AND company_uuid = in_company_uuid AND startdatetime < NOW() AND (enddatetime > NOW() OR enddatetime IS NULL);

    IF temp_count > 1 THEN

        out_status := 1;
        out_status_description := 'Invalid rows in costs table!';
        RETURN;

    ELSEIF temp_count = 1 THEN

        SELECT INTO temp_costs costs FROM costs WHERE costtype = 'MEMBERMESSAGE' AND company_uuid = in_company_uuid AND startdatetime < NOW() AND (enddatetime > NOW() OR enddatetime IS NULL);

    ELSE

        SELECT INTO temp_costs costs FROM costs WHERE costtype = 'MEMBERMESSAGE' AND company_uuid IS NULL AND startdatetime < NOW() AND (enddatetime > NOW() OR enddatetime IS NULL);

    END IF;

    IF temp_costs != in_messagecosts THEN

        out_status := 2;
        out_status_description := 'Message costs have changed during sending of the message';
        RETURN;

    ELSE

        SELECT INTO temp_balance balance FROM companies WHERE company_uuid = in_company_uuid;
        SELECT INTO temp_count COUNT(*) 
          FROM users 
          WHERE (user_uuid = ANY(in_destinationmemberuuids))
             OR (user_uuid IN (SELECT user_uuid FROM targetgroupusers WHERE targetgroup_uuid = ANY(in_destinationgroupuuids)) )
         GROUP BY user_uuid;

        temp_campaign_uuid := generate_uuid('campaigns', 'campaign_uuid');
        INSERT INTO campaigns (company_uuid, campaign_uuid, title, senddatetime, startdatetime, enddatetime, messagetype, state, message) VALUES (in_company_uuid, temp_campaign_uuid, in_title, NOW() + in_timedelta, NOW() + in_timedelta, NOW() + in_timedelta, 'MEMBERMESSAGE', 'DRAFT', in_messagecontents);

        IF in_timedelta > '00:00:00' THEN


        ELSE

            IF temp_balance < (temp_costs * temp_count) THEN

                UPDATE campaigns SET state = 'INACTIVE' WHERE campaign_uuid = temp_campaign_uuid;
                out_status := 2;
                out_status_description := 'Insufficient balance';
                RETURN;

            ELSE

                UPDATE campaigns SET state = 'ACTIVE' WHERE campaign_uuid = temp_campaign_uuid;

                UPDATE companies SET balance = (temp_balance - (temp_costs * temp_count)) WHERE company_uuid = in_company_uuid;

                SELECT INTO temp_destination_uuids array_agg(DISTINCT(user_uuid)) 
                  FROM users 
                  WHERE (user_uuid = ANY(in_destinationmemberuuids))
                     OR (user_uuid IN(SELECT user_uuid FROM targetgroupusers WHERE targetgroup_uuid = ANY(in_destinationgroupuuids)));
RAISE NOTICE 'Array is %', temp_destination_uuids;  


                FOR temp_record IN (SELECT u.firstname, m.mobilenumber FROM users AS u LEFT JOIN mobilenumbers AS m ON m.user_uuid = u.user_uuid WHERE u.user_uuid = ANY(temp_destination_uuids)) LOOP
                    IF temp_record.mobilenumber IS NOT NULL AND temp_record.mobilenumber != '' THEN
```

--**THIS IS WHERE IT GOES WRONG**
                            temp_mobilenumbers[temp_iterator] := ARRAY[temp_record.firstname::VARCHAR, temp_record.mobilenumber::VARCHAR];
                            temp_iterator := temp_iterator + 1;

```
                                 END IF;
                END LOOP;

                out_status := 0;
                out_status_description := 'Message created successfully';
                out_value := temp_mobilenumbers;

                RETURN;                                                 

            END IF;         

        END IF;

    END IF;

END$$;
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh god, after pulling almost all my hairs out looking at the loop part, i found out it went wrong in the declaration of the variable!

```
temp_iterator INTEGER;
```

Had to be

```
temp_iterator INTEGER := 0;
```

Ahhhh finally christmas time!

Comment: Which is exactly what the error message was telling you :-) Have good Christmas season.